# Extruding a circular shape from a non-circular object

Tags: topology, extrude

I need to extrude a circular shape from a surface that's basically just a grid of quads. What's the best practice to do this without screwing up the topology too much?

I basically want to have a circular face I can extrude, in order to have a cylinder like protuberance on the object, something like this:

[image]

Comment: your question is too vague, could you please make a screenshot of your object, or a drawing of what you want?

Comment: Done. Hope it's clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your mesh, you will have to select a number of faces to use as a circular entrance to the hole. The density of your example image suggests to use 2x2 (4) faces.

1. Select the faces and remove them. <kbd>X</kbd>
2. Position the cursor at the center of the desired hole and set the pivo point to cursor mode.
3. Select the vertices and make them ***to sphere*** <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>1</kbd> > <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.
4. Smooth them with the loop tools space option.
5. Add a circle with 8 vertices and bridge the remaining geometry. You know have a perfectly circular piece of geometry which you can extrude inwards.

[image: creating a hole]

The resulting topology
[image]

Comment: Off topic: Nice shader, how did you get that variable width wireframe rough look?

Comment: @Duarte I'm not sure why I can't find an answer, maybe add a Q&A if there isn't any yet. Unwrap > Reset. Then [this](https://i.imgur.com/UJhHwHH.gif).

Comment: Interesting technique, wouldn't have thought of that. Definitely deserves its own Q&A