# Making round features on cubes in hard surface modelling

Tags: modeling

Rather than just blindly following Youtube tutorials, I like to practice modelling by finding concept art I like and trying to model it in Blender. In this case I'm trying to model this robot:

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/3eGxY

I'm trying to replicate that big round lens in the robot's 'head', but I can't seem to do it and still have clean geometry. I have tried using a boolean to cut out the circle, then adding a sphere, but it results in a messy mesh.

[image: Messy robot mesh]

There are no doubt several better ways to achieve the same effect with much cleaner results. Any ideas?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118586

Comment: A boolean operation (almost) always results in messy geometry, but you can sometimes avoid or reduce it by preparing the faces where you cut out things with creating cuts to have smaller areas. Although in this case where you cut it out of a simple cube it shouldn't be that messy. The problem here looks like you  marked all those edges sharp and then beveled them.